# Look alternative to pprint for printing in Python

Tags: python, pprint

As we know, pprint can be "annoying" when it's printing list of a lot of small words, since pprint can only accept of two modes: one-line of multiple small words, or multiple lines of small words on each line separately.

Is there some other python library which can print the dict like {"1" : [1] * 10, "2": [2]*100} in a pretty while still compact way?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want it to print `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]` as `[5] * 10`?

Comment: I believe OP's intent is to keep output lines at reasonable length (80 characters?) by splitting longer lines.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `True` as the `compact` argument. (Only available in Python 3.4+)

```
>>> pprint({"1" : [1]*10, "2": [2]*100}, compact=True)
{'1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 '2': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2]}
```

Comment: It's great. However, my working place is still using Python 2.7. Is there a way to get similar in Python 2.7? Thanks..

Comment: I usually don't use Python 2, so I've got no idea. You could try to write a function that emulates this feature of Python 3's `pprint` or convince your team to switch to Python 3. :P Python 2 support stops in two and a half years so this would actually be a good idea.